# Obtaining cordinates of Moving ball in android game

Tags: java, android

I'm designing a moving ball game for Android. I'm using the thread for the movement of the ball around the screen. When I do the OnTouchEvent I'm able to obtain the X & Y coordinates of the screen wherever I tapped. My question here is how to obtain the values of X and Y coordinates of the ball for the same instance of the OnTouchEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is storing it's coordinates in every moment(for example in two fields) and use them,when user tapped.Or you can create a class for example Ball which it has fields that store coordinates of current instance ball and getter and setter for coordinates.

Comment: @SantoshVM Your question is vague,please add more commnet in about your question and add snippet code.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of your question, the coordinates of the ball is decided by one of your threads. That means, you should already have variables storing the x and y coordinates at any time.

All you need to do is to access those variables storing the x and y coordinates on the OnTouchEvent.